# Rewrite URL and redirect base url using htacesss

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i'm new at htaccess rewrite rule and regex expression
i'want to rewrite my base
url -> `/service/authentication/?step=1`
to -> /service/new/auth/1

step= is a parameter from 1 to 5

so my rule is :

```
RewriteRule ^new/auth/([^/.]+)?$ /service/index.php/authentication/?step=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new/auth/([^/.]+)?/$ /service/index.php/authentication/?step=$1 [L]
```

so when I access `/service/new/auth/8` in the url it work very good

so after that i'created a new rules to redirect the base url to the rewriten url

my rule is :

```
RewriteRule ^authentication/$ /service/new/auth/$1 [L,R]
```

the base url now redirect to `/service/new/auth/?step=1`

the problem it must redirect to `/service/new/auth/1`  without showing step=1 and the ? must be the id

i'think i have a problem in my regax

thanks for all helps

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. Make sure to place these rules before your rewrite rules(which I assume already present in your file).

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for external redirect goes from here....
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/service/authentication\?step=(\d+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /service/new/auth/%1? [R=301,L]
##rest of your rules for internal redirect/rewrite goes from here..
```

Comment: i tried your solution but still the same problem

Comment: @adnenmanssouri, please do let me know what sample URL you are hitting? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: when i enter the rewriten url it is working fine (/service/new/auth/1) but when i go to the base url (/service/authentication/?step=1) it must redirect to the rewriten url but it redirect fine to (to (/service/new/auth/?step=1) but there no id and step=1 must not be shown